# Why am I getting an exception in thread main error?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, program-entry-point

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseOrder
{

    char input;

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {


       Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

       char [] ch = new char[5];


      System.out.println ("The size of the array: " + ch.length);

      for (char index = 0; index < ch.length; index++)
      {
         System.out.print ("Enter a char " + (index+1) + ": ");
         ch[index] = reader.next().charAt(0);
      }

      System.out.println ("The numbers in reverse order:");

      for (char index = (char) (ch.length-1); index >= 0; index--)
         System.out.print (ch[index] + "  ");
       }

}
```

Comment: What exception, what's the stack trace tell you about what line number? DON'T MAKE US GUESS!

Comment: I'm new to Java.  I don't know what to do here.  If it's not too much trouble, could you copy and paste it in eclipse?

Comment: Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));

Comment: Write a program that takes 5 single characters 
instead of numbers as the input and outputs them 
in reverse order   < -- this was the question.  I got it to write the char in reverse order, but I get an error

Comment: this is the error I get 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
 at ReverseOrder.main(ReverseOrder.java:39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are suffering from a `char` overflow.

The main problem is with your loops...

```
for (char index = 0; index < ch.length; index++)
```

and

```
for (char index = (char) (ch.length-1); index >= 0; index--)
```

Which are using `char`.  Try changing them to use `int` instead, for example...

```
for (int index = 0; index < ch.length; index++)
```

and

```
for (int index = (ch.length-1); index >= 0; index--)
```

Comment: Oh wow.  Thank you so much.  I didn't realize it at first, but that makes perfect sense. I appreciate it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `char` for your `for loops`

Change to

```
for (int index = 0; index < ch.length; index++)
```

and

```
for (int index = ch.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing the char array.

You should make the following change:

Change

```
for (char index = (char) (ch.length-1); index >= 0; index--)
```

to

```
 for (int index =  ch.length-1; index >= 0; index--)
```

An example prints is as follows:

```
The size of the array: 5
Enter a char 1: 1
Enter a char 2: 2
Enter a char 3: 3
Enter a char 4: 4
Enter a char 5: 5
The numbers in reverse order:
5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  Really appreciate it.  This was very helpful